# Permission to not allow IAM USER instance to create new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to create a power-user who has all the permission on the existing instance, but he isn't able to create a new instance.

Which permission would manage that that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming "PowerUser" means all permissions, then you might want to try this permission

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
   ]
}
```

The first statement gives full permission to your user (please adapt to your definition of "PowerUser").  The second statement explicitly denies to call the EC2 API RunInstances (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html)

You can learn more about IAM Policies at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PoliciesOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are discussing EC2 permissions. To prevent creation of new instances, the [EC2 policy action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html) associated with this is `EC2:RunInstances`.

To specify a single instance, I'd suggest using a [condition block](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition) with a `ec2:ResourceTag/`. That gives more flexibility than hardcoding it in another manner. However, this will take some thought to prevent privilege escalation.

Comment: If I remove that permission,  will my already created instance "which are in stopped state" will "Start or not".
I was confused between startInstance and RunInstances .

Comment: RunInstances is to create new instances.  StartInstances is to start previously stopped instances

Comment: @SébastienStormacq I'll change it, but your answer is better anyhow.